# A complete Radio electronics guide

Tags: radio, transmitter, receiver

I want to learn all the basics about making a simple radio project.

The project is simple... **One transmitting device** (which only sends out analog signals of some decent frequency.. say 50MHz) and **one receiving device** which will have an LED and it will light up only when it receives the signal that is produced by the transmitter.

The project is simple.. I wish to learn everything from scratch and implement it using discrete semiconductor components (No not IC's)

I have searched most part in the internet and almost all of them just show only finalized circuit and thus there is no learning process involved.. I wish to learn the entire electronics/physics behind it as I implement it.. Any Book/link will will do...

Comment: I have even implemented a crude FM radio transmitter.. But I found absolutely no content on simple receiver on the internet

Comment: I too have seen countless schematics of FM receivers and have even made few, but so far I was unable to actually find a guide with a nice, easy to understand and thorough description of what's happening.

Comment: so u understand my problem @AndrejaKo...

Comment: The books I've tried, the ARRL ones for example, go from fairly basic to complex really quickly. Good for a reference I guess but not really for the beginner. In the same boat. Did some basic EMC courses but not ehough I guess.

Comment: I think something in the khz range would be much easier though...

Comment: Blob, did you pursue your project? Did you find anything useful? I would also like to learn about radio but there is not too much information on that on the web

Comment: @Speccy I just left the project after i made a simple fm transmitter. I agree.. There is surprisingly little info available on the web.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [The Electronics of Radio](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521646456). It provides a filter by filter, oscillator by oscillator guide of building a radio. The end result radio might be more complicated than what you are looking for, but I found the explanations and problems to be helpful in my understanding of electronics.

This book was written by a professor specifically for a class he teaches. Disclaimer: I took that class.

Comment: I will have a look at that book as soon as possible.. Fully Fledged radio design will be perfect for me if it teaches me how all the parts(at the root level) work beforehand..